# Why does this webpage flicker a lot on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, flicker

The webpage which I am currently front end coding is https://www.softpaz.com/software/download-jetbrains-webstorm-windows-180745.htm

**Issue is that the**

1) sidebar sometimes gets transparent

2) div background are blank, then suddenly appear and then go blank again.

3) The buy links table has flickering borders

4) Most of the small icons are flickering

These things happen when scrolling in Microsoft Edge, and IE11. Have tested the same webpage in chrome and firefox, and its working without any issues.

**I have tried:**

- http://ieflicker.com/
- tried removing the background, removing box shadows, text shadows, disable rounded corners and put everything at 100% opacity, but it still happens.

When the page is small, that is, there are less number of elements on the page, like the about us page of softpaz(link on top top right) then everything display fine.

**Am confused on what to do now!?**

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  Also please read this: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: @Pete Yes Pete, I understand that. I have read a lot on Google since the last couple of hours, and tried many solutions. The more elements I remove from the webpage, the less flickery it becomes. But there are bigger websites which do not flicker. I feel maybe I am just missing something silly.

Comment: probably something to do with the type of css you are using and whether the page has to repaint itself when you scroll

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Posting it if someone is facing the same problem. My system has the Intel HD3000 and running on Windows 10, which means that there was **limited hardware acceleration support**(as there are no official drivers from Intel). The page runs fine on other systems.

Once again, I see that Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc outshine IE/Edge on the same system!

Comment: This is very helpful. The processors that my system has are INTEL i5-4570 and I'm facing same rendering issues on IE and Edge.

Comment: @gkri have you tried the latest Intel drivers available at https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26984/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-?product=81496

Comment: Just tried, I seem to always get the error "This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software"